# Can't get JAXB to handle interfaces with simple example

Tags: java, xml, jaxb2

I'm trying the simple example for JAXB Interfaces shown at [Unofficial JAXB Guide - Mapping interfaces — Project Kenai](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch03.html#Use__XmlRootElement), section 3.2.1 and it won't work for me. I'm in latest JDK 1.8_70 and not using any special libraries. Code for completeness sake:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Zoo {
  @XmlAnyElement
  public List<Animal> animals;
}

interface Animal {
  void sleep();
  void eat();
  ...
}

@XmlRootElement
class Dog implements Animal { ... }

@XmlRootElement
class Lion implements Animal { ... }
```

Any help on this? The error I'm getting is:

```
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: class testjaxb.Cat nor any of its super class is known to this context.
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class testjaxb.Cat nor any of its super class is known to this context.]
```

EDIT: Posted JAXBContext.newInstance code:

```
Zoo zoo = new Zoo();
zoo.animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
zoo.animals.add( new Cat() );
zoo.animals.add( new Dog() );
zoo.animals.add( new Dog() );

JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Zoo.class);
Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
marshaller.marshal(zoo, System.out);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try specifying the other classes in the list you provide to `JAXBContext.newInstance()`.

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Zoo.class, Cat.class, Dog.class);
```

Applying the `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation to your `Zoo` class should also work.

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso({Cat.class, Dog.class})
class Zoo {
    ...
}
```