# Schema won't validate java with interface example

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

Sort of a follow-up to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35184975/cant-get-jaxb-to-handle-interfaces-with-simple-example). I made a simple XML from [Unofficial JAXB Guide - Mapping interfaces — Project Kenai](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Mapping_interfaces.html#Use__XmlRootElement), and generated a schema with `schemagen` from the *.java files. The classes use an `interface`, but the schema won't validate the XML. This should be simple to do, but I guess I don't understand the `XmlAnyElement` annotation and the resulting `xs:any` schema element it generates. Here is simple example code:

```
@XmlRootElement
class Zoo {
  @XmlAnyElement
  public List<Animal> animals;
}

interface Animal {}

@XmlRootElement
class Dog implements Animal {}

@XmlRootElement
class Cat implements Animal {}
```

My JABContext.newInstance() and property:

```
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Zoo.class, Dog.class, Cat.class);
Marshaller marshaller = ctx.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "schema1.xsd");
marshaller.marshal(zoo, writer);
```

And the XML generated:

```
<zoo xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schema1.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><cat/><dog/><dog/><cat/><dog/><dog/></zoo>
```

And the schema generated, again by schemagen:

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="cat" type="cat"/>
  <xs:element name="dog" type="dog"/>
  <xs:element name="zoo" type="zoo"/>
  <xs:complexType name="cat">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="dog">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="zoo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any processContents="skip" namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

The error I'm getting, which is from Eclipse (Jboss developer studio 9.1.0Beta1) is:

```
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'cat'. One of '{WC[##other:""]}' is expected.
```

I'm trying to figure out what to do, but I'd hoped that I wouldn't have to do anything by hand. I could generate the schema with a `jaxb-maven-plugin`, but it's the same. Any help appreciated. Hopefully it's not an Eclipse error. One of the big reasons I generated the schema in the first place was to get rid of the validation errors in Eclipse.